# Vaadin grid.setItems not working in propertyChange methode

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14, vaadin-grid, propertychangelistener

I have created a vaadin application using vaadin 14, i have a class accordion that passes an object HandlerTest to class Grid using a propertyChange listener. The object do pass to the grid class but when i try to use grid.setItems to show it it doesn't work. grid.setItems does add the object if i add it from the constructer but don't if i add it from the propertyChange methode.
Here is the code i used for bothe classes and the main class:

the Grid class:
`

```
package org.vaadin.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Route("grid")
public final class GridClass extends VerticalLayout implements PropertyChangeListener {
    HandlerTest ht = new HandlerTest();
    List<HandlerTest> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Grid<HandlerTest> grid = new Grid<>();

    public GridClass() {

        grid.addColumn(HandlerTest::getPattern).setHeader("Pattern");
        grid.addColumn(HandlerTest::getModuleName).setHeader("Module");

        grid.setItems(list);
        grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
        grid.setAllRowsVisible(true);
        grid.setHeight("480px");
        add(grid);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

        HandlerTest newHandler = (HandlerTest) evt.getNewValue();
        ht = newHandler;

        list.add(ht);

        Notification.show("Value of obj :" + evt.getNewValue());
        grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
    }
}
```

`

here is the HandlerTest class:

`

```
package org.vaadin.example;

public class HandlerTest implements java.io.Serializable{
    private String moduleName;
    private String pattern;
    private String method;
    private String sourceType;
    private String itemsPerPage;
    private String mimesAllowed;
    private String comments;
    private String pSource;

    public HandlerTest(String moduleName, String pattern, String method, String sourceType, String itemsPerPage, String mimesAllowed, String comments, String pSource) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.method = method;
        this.sourceType = sourceType;
        this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
        this.mimesAllowed = mimesAllowed;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.pSource = pSource;
    }

    public HandlerTest() {
    }


    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    public String getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public void setPattern(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String getSourceType() {
        return sourceType;
    }

    public void setSourceType(String sourceType) {
        this.sourceType = sourceType;
    }

    public String getItemsPerPage() {
        return itemsPerPage;
    }

    public void setItemsPerPage(String itemsPerPage) {
        this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    }

    public String getMimesAllowed() {
        return mimesAllowed;
    }

    public void setMimesAllowed(String mimesAllowed) {
        this.mimesAllowed = mimesAllowed;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getpSource() {
        return pSource;
    }

    public void setpSource(String pSource) {
        this.pSource = pSource;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return moduleName + "/" + pattern + "/" + method + "/" + sourceType + "/" + itemsPerPage + "/" + mimesAllowed 
                + "/" + comments + "/" + pSource ;
    }
    
    public HandlerTest createHandlerFromString(HandlerTest h){
       
        String[] handlerText = (h.toString()).split("/");
        HandlerTest handler = new HandlerTest(handlerText[0], handlerText[1], handlerText[2], handlerText[3], 
                handlerText[4], handlerText[5], handlerText[6], handlerText[7]);

        return handler;
    }

}
```

`

i was expecting the grid to be refreshed and the item is added but nothing happened. The notification shows the object to display but the grid don't add it.

Comment: There's lots of things in your example that isn't related to the question you're asking. Could you please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you tell me what exactly should i reduce? i removed all commants and unneeded methods that i have, is the code not worknig ?

Comment: One example of not being reproducible is that the `HandlerTest` class is missing. One example of not being minimal is that a `HandlerTest` class is needed in the first place since the type of the data shouldn't really have anything to do with doing updates in a property change listener.

Comment: yes ! true, realy sorry, ill add it now!

Comment: Remove, don't add! The longer you make the code example, the more intimidating it will look which in turn reduces the chances that anyone will actually have a proper look.

Comment: As another example: why is a form layout needed for showcasing a problem with Grid?

Comment: the handlerTest is passed from the form in accordion to the grid in gridclass, and if i remove anymore of the code it will stop working, the accordion is a bit long though

Comment: That doesn't sound even close to minimal to me

Comment: should i remove the accordion class?

Comment: You should remove everything that isn't directly related to the problem you're trying to solve. Here's an example of what a minimal reproducible example would look like based on the description about not being able to update Grid items from a property change event: https://gist.github.com/Legioth/0d00a5daba53ef8ca1c257d24e253f9c

That example works as expected, which means that the actual problem is probably something else. By working to reduce your example to something resembling my minimal example, you will most likely discover what the actual problem is.

Comment: i have removed the accordion class, and the main class that is just there to call them, the accordion class is doing his job sending the object, thats why i'm sure that the problem is in the gridclass, btw, thank you for taking the time to show me how to work with stackoverflow,

Comment: It's not reproducible now since there isn't anything there that ever even tries to create an instance of `HandlerTest`.